# How to redirect verbose garbage collection output to a file?

Tags: garbage-collection, java, java-5

How do I redirect verbose garbage collection output to a file?  Sun’s website shows an example for Unix but it doesn't work for Windows.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

From the output of `java -X`:

```
    -Xloggc:<file>    log GC status to a file with time stamps
```

Documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> **-Xloggc:*filename***
>
> Sets the file to which verbose GC events information should be redirected for logging. The information written to this file is similar to the output of `-verbose:gc` with the time elapsed since the first GC event preceding each logged event. The `-Xloggc` option overrides `-verbose:gc` if both are given with the same `java` command.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>     -Xloggc:garbage-collection.log
> ```

So the output looks something like this:

```
0.590: [GC 896K->278K(5056K), 0.0096650 secs]
0.906: [GC 1174K->774K(5056K), 0.0106856 secs]
1.320: [GC 1670K->1009K(5056K), 0.0101132 secs]
1.459: [GC 1902K->1055K(5056K), 0.0030196 secs]
1.600: [GC 1951K->1161K(5056K), 0.0032375 secs]
1.686: [GC 1805K->1238K(5056K), 0.0034732 secs]
1.690: [Full GC 1238K->1238K(5056K), 0.0631661 secs]
1.874: [GC 62133K->61257K(65060K), 0.0014464 secs]
```

Comment: java --Xloggc:firstgen.log -Xloggc:secondgen.log doesn't seem to work by the way.

Comment: Also, this doesnt increase the output, as I expected.  There are no additional details after using these arguments:

-Xloggc:gc.log -XX:-PrintGCDetails

Comment: "-XX:+PrintGCDetails" seems to work with -Xloggc. I don't know why the Sun page has a - instead of a +.

Comment: that worked. thanks!  now, i use these options:   set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xloggc:logs\gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Answer (score 38):

If in addition you want to pipe the output to a separate file, you can do:

On a **Sun JVM:**

```
-Xloggc:C:\whereever\jvm.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

ON an **IBM JVM:**

```
-Xverbosegclog:C:\whereever\jvm.log
```

Comment: If you use -Xloggc, you don't need -verbose:gc.

Answer (score 15):

## Java 9 & Unified JVM Logging

[JEP 158](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) introduces a common logging system for all components of the JVM which will change (and IMO simplify) how logging works with GC. JEP 158 added a new command-line option to control logging from all components of the JVM:

```
-Xlog
```

For example, the following option:

```
-Xlog:gc
```

will log messages tagged with `gc` tag using `info` level to `stdout`. Or this one:

```
-Xlog:gc=debug:file=gc.txt:none
```

would log messages tagged with `gc` tag using `debug` level to a file called `gc.txt` with no decorations. For more detailed discussion, you can checkout the examples in the [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) page.

Comment: With JDK 16 you even get a warning if you use the old `-Xloggc` instead of `-Xlog:gc:...`

Comment: How can I append the log to an existing file?

Answer (score 8):

To add to the above answers, there's a good article: [Useful JVM Flags – Part 8 (GC Logging)](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/) by Patrick Peschlow.

A brief excerpt:

The flag **`-XX:+PrintGC`** (or the alias `-verbose:gc`) activates the “simple” GC logging mode

By default the GC log is written to stdout. With **`-Xloggc:<file>`** we may instead specify an output file. Note that this flag implicitly sets `-XX:+PrintGC` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` as well.

If we use **`-XX:+PrintGCDetails`** instead of `-XX:+PrintGC`, we activate the “detailed” GC logging mode which differs depending on the GC algorithm used.

With **`-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`** a timestamp reflecting the real time passed in seconds since JVM start is added to every line.

If we specify **`-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`** each line starts with the absolute date and time.