# How to get java stdout when running as isapi extension in IIS

Tags: java, iis, java-native-interface, isapi

For debugging I need to inspect the java stdout (in this case the -verbose:class). The java code is running as isapi extension. But IIS does swallow default all stdout. Redirecting System.out from java does not work, because java -verbose is sent to stdout directly and not by System.out. Any solution/workaround to still get the verbose output?

Comment: Which part of `verbose` are you after? If GC, then see [How to redirect verbose garbage collection output to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1161647/5221149)

Comment: Thanks. I need classloading output (-verbose:class) and as far as I know this can not be redirected to a file. Updated question.