# Difference between -XX:+PrintGC and -verbose:gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

I want to understand the difference between:
`-XX:+PrintGC` and `-verbose:gc`
Apparently these look similar.

This article doesn't list the `verbose:gc`
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

I also saw these two questions: [How to redirect verbose garbage collection output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161647/how-to-redirect-verbose-garbage-collection-output-to-a-file) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1818039/2266682
but couldn't get much understanding.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JDK 8 `-verbose:gc` is [an exact alias](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2730) for `-XX:+PrintGC`.

However, `-verbose:gc` is a standard option, while `-XX:+PrintGC` is not.

`-XX:+PrintGC` is deprecated since JDK 9 in favor of unified logging option `-Xlog:gc`, see [JEP 158](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158).
`-verbose:gc` still works in JDK 9 and 10.

Comment: Not clear about `-verbose:gc`. Does it do anything in JDK9+? Or `-Xlog:gc` is enough

Comment: @turbanoff `-verbose:gc` acts exactly like `-Xlog:gc`