# Enabling garbage collection logging with Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat

Tags: java, garbage-collection, tomcat8, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my terraform deployment I have settings

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    name = "Xms"
    value = "2048m"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    name = "Xmx"
    value = "2048m"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    name = "JVM Options"
    value = "-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:log/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M"
  }
```

In the container options, I can see that the `Xms`, `Xmx` and GC settings were applied. But when I download full logs from the container I can not find GC logs anywhere. What could be an issue? I read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161647/how-to-redirect-verbose-garbage-collection-output-to-a-file) with the common GC setup, but it does not work in my case. I use `Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.1.0`

[image]

Comment: Please provide the full `Dockerrun.aws.json`, second, did you define the awslogs as log driver that the logs can be only view in `cloudwatch`? thrid, the logs something saved in container or ec2 instances some where, did you login the ec2 instances and search them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue you are facing is permission. You are starting the service under `tomcat` user so it has no access to that path to create logs.

Try out this `-Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat8/gc.log`